# Obtaining strings from BitStruct in Python's construct module

Tags: python, data-structures

I am using the Python [construct](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) parser to process some binary data but am not managing to obtain strings in the way I expected.

Note that in the simplified example below I could use [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) or even just a slice, but the real data I am parsing does not align neatly to byte boundaries.

Some example code:

```
from construct import BitStruct, BitField, Padding, String

struct = BitStruct("foo",
  BitField("bar", 8),
  BitField("baz", 16),
  Padding(4),
  BitField("bat", 4)
)

struct2 = BitStruct("foo",
  BitField("bar", 8),
  String("baz", 16),
  Padding(4),
  BitField("bat", 4)
)

data = "\x01AB\xCD"

print struct.parse(data)
print struct2.parse(data)
```

This prints the output:

```
Container:
    bar = 1
    baz = 16706
    bat = 13
Container:
    bar = 1
    baz = '\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
    bat = 13
```

I was expecting that [String](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/string.html) would give me back `AB` as an actual string.  However it is returning the equivalent binary string instead.

How can I persuade construct to return me the actual ASCII string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating an [Adapter](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/adapters.html).  The original ASCII values are parsed into a list of integers which can then be converted into a string representation.

It's not the most elegant way but due to BitStruct operating only on bit values it seems to be the easiest workaround.  An improved version would parse different length strings (e.g. 7-bit ASCII).

```
from binascii import hexlify
from construct import BitStruct, BitField, Padding, Array, Octet, Adapter

class BitStringAdapter(Adapter):
  def _encode(self, obj, context):
    return list(ord(b) for b in obj)
  def _decode(self, obj, context):
    return "".join(chr(b) for b in obj)

struct = BitStruct("foo",
  BitField("bar", 8),
  BitStringAdapter(Array(2, Octet("baz"))),
  Padding(4),
  BitField("bat", 4)
)

data = "\x01AB\xCD"

out = struct.parse(data)
print hexlify(struct.build(out))
```

This outputs:

```
Container:
    bar = 1
    baz = 16706
    bat = 13
0141420d
```

Which is correct - the `C` byte is discarded because it's marked as padding, this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The python module [bitstruct](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstruct/3.1.0) can also be used to parse bit fields. It uses format strings, just like the standard library struct module.

The format specifier 't' is for text.

```
>>> from bitstruct import unpack
>>> data = b'\x01AB\xCD'
>>> unpack("u8u16p4u4", data)
(1, 16706, 13)
>>> unpack("u8t16p4u4", data)
(1, u'AB', 13)
```